# Flash AS3 - how to go to specific scene on external swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to start on specific scene on my loaded external swf file?

Answer (score 0):

By scene, I'm going to assume you mean a specific frame. You're going to want to load your SWF, listen for it to complete, and invoke e.currentTarget.content.gotoAndStop(FRAME_NUMBER), where e is your Event and FRAME_NUMBER is the frame you're wanting to start on.